# Can I use Azure Data Factory to turn base64 encoded bytes from Graph API back into a file?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-data-factory

I'm running into an issue with Microsoft Graph API and Azure Data Factory.
I'm making a call to Graph API to grab an email file attachment from an inbox. This returns the files content in bytes. To my knowledge, these bytes are base64 encoded.

Here is where my problem comes into play. I can't find a solution for converting the bytes back into an excel file. My attempts so far have just left me an excel file with a single column that's just the bytes as a single string.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Edit:
I don't have much sample code, mainly because of just a lack of anything coming even close to working. What I can provide is details of the current pipeline and some of the tools I've attempted using.

My pipeline is set up to call all emails received from a given email address using Graph API and the web activity in ADF, then for each message (using a foreach loop for each messageId returned by the web call), it will call the attachment.

The call for an attachment returns email attachments in a json with fields including fileName (name of the file with .pdf or .xls tag), contentBytes (contents of the file encoded in base64), fileType (type of the file in a format like application/pdf), attachmentId (id assigned to the email attachment), and some more that I am not currently focused on.

The column contentBytes is the important record here. I have tried using base64tostring() in various locations to try and convert the value back into a string while it's moving, with no success.

I usually end up with a file with contentBytes written followed by the original byte value returned, regardless if I try saving as a .txt, .csv, or .xls. I'm at a wall and don't know where to go from here.

Comment: To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.

Comment: @NaveenSharma I've made some edits, I apologize if it's not enough. I've hit a wall and my attempts have just been not converting the string or returning a simple mapping error.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you got the expected string from the `base64`, ADF cannot create the respective `.pdf`, `.xlsx` based on the incoming string.

You can try logic app as workaround to achieve your requirement.

Use **HTTP** get request in logic app to get all message ids from graph API URL.

Give the output body array from above HTTP request to a for-each loop.
Inside loop, call the attachements using another **HTTP** `GET` request like below.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/<message_id>/attachments
```

[image]

After this, use `Create Blob` action and create Blob storage connetion. In this action, give the below dynamic expression for **Blob name** and **Blob content** from the above `HTTP` body.

```
Blob name - body('HTTP')?['value'][0]?['name']
Blob content - base64ToString(body('HTTP')?['value'][0]?['contentBytes'])
```

[image]

Run the logic app and the respective files will be generated like below from the mail.

[image]

Comment: Given logic apps are going away in August of this year and my solution is meant to last for a while, I didn't want to take the Logic App route. I've just given up and written an Azure Function App to perform the conversion for me. It's not the ADF solution I was hoping for but it's better than nothing.